# Rails 3 - select data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join, include

I have these 3 models:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :car_styles
  has_many :styles, :through => :car_styles
end


class CarStyle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :style
end


class UserStyle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :style
  belongs_to :user  
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base     
  has_many :cars

  has_many :car_styles
  has_many :styles, :through => :car_styles
```

end

I have logged-in a user (**current_user**). I am trying to select all cars, where **car style_id** are the same like **user style_id** -- how can I do that?

Thanks for help in advance

**EDIT:** schema:

### cars

```
-id
-user_id
```

### car_styles

```
-car_id
-style_id
```

### user_styles

```
-user_id
-style_id
```

Every user has saved favorite styles - doesn't matter how much (but approximately ±5). Every photo has added a styles as well - and again doesn't matter how much.

And I would like to select all cars from table Cars, which have the same styles, as the current_user has added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're saying here is you have three main models:

Car, User and Style

CarStyle and UserStyle are joins right?

If so, you should be able to say:

```
Car.joins(:styles => [:users]).where(:users => {:id => current_user.id })
```

If not, could you update the question with your schema?

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this query unfortunately doesn't works me, I updated my question.

Comment: When I try this it seems to work fine: https://github.com/Bodacious/CarUserStyles

I created a bunch of Cars and gave half of them the same styles as a user and half of them not. It returns those cars that do...

Comment: you'll have to add .uniq at the end to prevent duplicate records though... `Car.joins(:styles => [:users]).where(:users => {:id => current_user.id }).uniq`

Comment: you absolutely made my day... right now I am solving DISTINCT of the getting results :) Thanks!!! And your original query was right, I had a failure in my `style` model. Thank you one more time!

Comment: and if I think about it yet - how could I get all rows, except mine?

Comment: You're welcome :) If you want all Cars that don't match the current_user's styles then you could try: `Car.joins(:styles => [:users]).where(["users.id != ?", current_user.id]).uniq`

Comment: I meant all cars except my cars `Car.joins(:styles => [:users]).where(["cars.user_id != ?", current_user.id]).uniq` - this query I needed. But one more time - many thanks!